# How can I check in new files to a brand new solution?

Tags: tfs

I added a project to a solution checked into a team foundation server solution and the individual project I just added does not offer me the ability to check it in. Has anyone faced this in past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always add the individual folder to the TFS through Team Explorer if you cannot do it automatically inside visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you checked in the new project but I think that you did not check in the solution file *.sln.
Each project in your solution is defined in the *.sln file.
simply check in the solution file and it will appear.